# Instantiate object attributes with content of parsed/sliced substrings?

Tags: python, string, object, substring

Expert Pythonistas,

the problem as follows:

I have a mainframe AS/400 extraction made in JSON manipulated into a 'long' single string to be further sliced / sub-stringed (if that's a word). The parsing outcome create instance of a model with several attributes. Those attributes generate a `OrderedDict()` to be again serialized (this is because in the future, the source of data may change and I need to maintain the abstraction at this level). I learned from recent studies that the best way to maintain a attribute / data that is `''` (empty string) as `None` to be best analyzed in the future.

```
for i, line in enumerate(data_json):
    swap_string += line['data']
    if data_json[i] == data_json[-1] or data_json[i+1]['data'][1] == '_':
        swap_list.append(swap_string)
        swap_string = ''
```

And here is the raw outcome:

```
_ D 958.860 L B NA0.000 010 N 001 U 0 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 999 T00 000 99 999 -/- 001 BG/CODEBEDINGUNGEN : BG F04/F07/F20;
```

Then, with this string, I have a 'map' or a 'header' that produces the object that can be serialized slicing and so on:

```
slices = ['3:23', '23:24', '26:27', '29:38', '39:42', '43:46', '48:50', '51:52', '53:54', '55:58', '61:67', '72:79']
```

than, with this, I request the class to instantiate and create these attributes:

```
def __init__(self, bm=None, kg=None, abm_saa=None, la=None, lt=None,
                   bu_su=None, pos=None, hws=None, sp=None, r=None, p=None,
                   asa=None, em_ab=None, em_bis=None, benennung=None,
                   asb=None, t_a=None, vkfbez=None, pws1=None, qu1=None,
                   pws2=None, qu2=None, da=None, anz=None, t_b=None,
                   bg=None, code=None, pruef=None, add_info=None):
    self.bm = bm
    self.kg = kg
    self.abm_saa = abm_saa...
```

and then comes the question:

My question is: Using the list with slice delimitations, how to instantiate the object with a for loop into the correct attribute applying a list comprehension? Is also possible to do a loop with the attributes from the class? Also, apply the empty strings as `None` in the object with a simple `if` statement?

```
for data in swap_list:
    for slice_str in slices:
        agr = PdsAGRMZDataModels()
        agr.abm_saa = data[slice_str].strip()
        agr.la = data[slice_str].strip()
```

Comment: Thank for the formatting @martineau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the correlation between the values in the slices array and the raw string presented above them but, based on the rest of the explanation I believe you could proceed as follows:

1) convert the slices array to a numeric form usable as string ranges: (only do this once if the ranges are the same for every row of data)

```
ranges = [ (int(r[0]),int(r[1])) for r in [ s.split(":") for s in slices] ]
```

2) For each row in your data set, extract the parameter values based on the ranges:

```
params = [ [p,None][p==''] for p in [ line[start:end].strip() for start,end in ranges ] ]

# Note: [p,None][p==''] is a compact alternative to:  None if p == '' else p
```

3) use the parameter value list with unpacking (*) to instantiate your model object: (this assumes that the slice ranges are in the same order as the constructor's parameters)

```
agr = PdsAGRMZDataModels(*params)

# Based on your sample data and slices this would produce seemingly
# misaligned data content.  
#
# agr.bm       == '958.860 L B NA0.000'
# agr.kg       == None
# agr.abm_saa  == '0'
# ...
```

[EDIT] avoiding the positional issue:

If you want to work around the parameter position/count constraint, you could use a dictionary structure for the slice definitions so that the extracted data gets associated names that match the function parameters.

For example:

```
 slices = { 'kg':(3,23), 'bm':(23,24), 'xyz':(5,52) }
```

Using the slices dictionary, the line's data can produce named values in a dictionary as well:

```
 data = { p:[v,None][v==''] for p,v in [(p,line[r[0]:r[1]].strip()) for p,r in slices.items()] }
```

Then, you can use the inspect module to obtain the list of arguments for the PdsAGRMZDataModels() constructor and map them, in the right order, to the named values you do have (and use None for values you don't have).  This mapping will always produce the right number of parameters in the appropriate order (independently of the source data).

[EDIT]: getargspec to getfullargspec

```
 import inspect
 params = [data[arg] if arg in data else None for arg in inspect.getfullargspec(PdsAGRMZDataModels).args[1:]]
 # Note that, because we're calling a method, I'm dropping 
 # the first argument which corresponds to "self" and doesn't count.
```

With this, you can safely call the model constructor using any source data and your solution will be a lot more resilient to API changes or input structure changes.  You could even give multiple names to the same slices if you're calling several different functions (with different parameter names) from the same data.

```
agr = PdsAGRMZDataModels(*params)
# The constructor gets bm= and kg= in the right order, 
# and None for all other parameters.  
# The xyz value is ignored since PdsAGRMZDataModels() has no such parameter.
```

Comment: Hi @Alain T., thank you for the insights. I learned a lot with them. One further question that I also had reading another post where the `ClassName(*params)` is cited is if the order of the parameters should be the same as the ranges (slices)? Now that the question is posted is more Heuristic but still a valid doubt. Also, unfortunatelly this method is user heavy dependent. Do you know some alternative (RegEx, machine_learning parsing tool, etc) that could provide a less Human Interfered process?

Comment: the inspection method added in your edit is also really good answer. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: just a headsup: inspect.getargspec is deprecated. Either use inspect.signature or inspect.getfullargspec. I the latter with sucess.